# Wavetable sampling variation

Tags: signal-processing, pic, waveform, synthesizer, sound-synthesis

I am interested in making a simple digital synthesizer to be implemented on an 8bit MCU. I would like to make wavetables for accurate representations of the sound. Standard wavetables seem to either have a table for several frequencies or to have a single sample that has fractional increments with missing data interpolated by the program to create different frequencies.

Would it be possible to create a single table for a given waveform, likely of a low frequency and change the rate at which the program polls the table to generate different frequencies which would then be processed. My MCU (free one, no budget) is rather slow so I don't have the space for lots of wavetables nor for large amounts of processing so I am trying to skimp where I can. Has anyone seen this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a single table with a phase accumulator and linear interpolation. See [this question on DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-to-create-a-sine-wave-generator-that-can-smoothly-transition-between-frequen/1044#1044) for many useful suggestions.

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of a whole board for DSP. For others who might find my question, Paul R's response in the linked thread is an excellent solution.